# Is it possible to set a checkpoint in multithreaded program?

Tags: multithreading, gdb

I have to debug program with multiple threads. I use gdb, and I'd like to use checkpoints. The only limitation in the [manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Checkpoint_002fRestart.html#Checkpoint_002fRestart) is that checkpoints are only available on gnu/linux systems, but nothing related to threads.

However, when I try to checkpoint, I have an error:

```
(gdb) checkpoint
checkpoint: can't checkpoint multiple threads.
```

Is there something I am doing wrong, or is it indeed not possible to checkpoint multi-threaded programs (with this limitation not listed in the manual) ?

---

N.B.: I am well aware that the notion of checkpoint/rollback is really difficult in a concurrent system, due to the causality aspects of such programs, the question is more about if there is something I am missing.

Comment: See gdb bug [12628](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12628).

Comment: @ssbssa perfect, thank you.

Comment: I would be happy if gdb only did the checkpoint operation in one thread, completely ignoring the other thread.